# OpenCV-Java Click a shape with mouse and change its color

Tags: java, opencv

Assume that we have a shape on black screen such as:
[Blue shape on black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gJoL.png)

I want to click to this shape with mouse and want that shape's color change. For example, after clicking: 
[Gray shape on black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj57f.png)

I know I can do it with shape detection and with a mouse click event or just changing matrix's values. I tried them but these two solutions are a little bit long for my project. I am just looking for a simple OpenCV method that I can do this operation much more efficient.

Maybe some function which can do the same job with Photoshop's "Magic Wand Tool" can be useful. I searched on internet but I cannot find any solution so I want to ask here. Again, good to remember, I can implement the solution but I just need a method in some framework.

Comment: 1) get the mask of the object 2) get x,y, of the mouse click, 3) if (mask(y,x) > 0) then 4) image.setTo(somecolor, mask), 5) done ;D    Magic Wand should be based on _grabcut_ or similar... will be definitely a less efficient approach

Comment: I did not understand "3) if (mask(y,x) > 0) then 4) image.setTo(somecolor, mask)," part. Now, I can get x and y coordinates but I cannot apply mask on them